React Highcharts issue with hydration
I have a chart that represent some data. That chart have toggle to switch between 2 type of units ( Mwh and Kwh ).
When data are init loaded, they are 100% correct and they are placed where they need to be.
But after the toggling, it make some 'issue'.
Data that are passed as series options, they are correct, but the blocks in graph are not correct placed.
There are screenshots of the issue:





I tried to use static data, not sorted one but there is still same issue.
Also, I tried to redraw chart but not help.
Here is part of code:
  const setBuildingNamesAndDataForChart = (sortedData: BuildingData[]) => {
    const tempNames: string[] = [];
    const districtHeatings: number[] = [];
    const districtCoolings: number[] = [];
    const gasImports: number[] = [];
    const electricityDemands: number[] = [];
    const electricityGenerations: number[] = [];
    const co2Uses: number[] = [];
    const energyUses: number[] = [];

    sortedData.forEach(
      ({
        building,
        year,
        USED_HEATING_IMPORT,
        DISTRICT_HEATING_IMPORT,
        USED_COOLING_IMPORT,
        DISTRICT_COOLING_IMPORT,
        USED_GAS_IMPORT,
        GAS_IMPORT_KWH,
        USED_ELECTRICITY_DEMAND,
        ELECTRICITY_DEMAND,
        USED_ELECTRICITY_GENERATION,
        ELECTRICITY_GENERATION,
        CO2_USE,
      }) => {
        tempNames.push(`${building.buildingName} ${year}`);

        districtHeatings.push(
          parseFloat(
            (toggleState
              ? USED_HEATING_IMPORT ?? 0
              : (DISTRICT_HEATING_IMPORT ?? 0) / 1000
            ).toFixed(1)
          )
        );
        districtCoolings.push(
          parseFloat(
            (toggleState
              ? USED_COOLING_IMPORT ?? 0
              : (DISTRICT_COOLING_IMPORT ?? 0) / 1000
            ).toFixed(1)
          )
        );
        gasImports.push(
          parseFloat(
            (toggleState
              ? USED_GAS_IMPORT ?? 0
              : (GAS_IMPORT_KWH ?? 0) / 1000
            ).toFixed(1)
          )
        );
        electricityDemands.push(
          parseFloat(
            (toggleState
              ? USED_ELECTRICITY_DEMAND ?? 0
              : (ELECTRICITY_DEMAND ?? 0) / 1000
            ).toFixed(1)
          )
        );
        electricityGenerations.push(
          parseFloat(
            (toggleState
              ? (USED_ELECTRICITY_GENERATION ?? 0) * -1
              : (ELECTRICITY_GENERATION ?? 0) / -1000
            ).toFixed(1)
          )
        );
        co2Uses.push(parseFloat((CO2_USE ?? 0).toFixed(1)));
      }
    );

    setBuildingNames(tempNames);
    setDataForChart([
      districtHeatings,
      districtCoolings,
      gasImports,
      electricityDemands,
      electricityGenerations,
      co2Uses,
      energyUses,
    ]);
  };

  const sortOnToggle = (data: BuildingData[]): BuildingData[] => {
    return [...data].sort((a, b) => {
      const sumA = toggleState
        ? (a.USED_HEATING_IMPORT ?? 0) +
          (a.USED_COOLING_IMPORT ?? 0) +
          (a.USED_GAS_IMPORT ?? 0) +
          (a.USED_ELECTRICITY_DEMAND ?? 0) +
          (a.USED_ELECTRICITY_GENERATION ?? 0)
        : (a.DISTRICT_HEATING_IMPORT ?? 0) +
          (a.DISTRICT_COOLING_IMPORT ?? 0) +
          (a.GAS_IMPORT_KWH ?? 0) +
          (a.ELECTRICITY_DEMAND ?? 0) +
          (a.ELECTRICITY_GENERATION ?? 0);

      const sumB = toggleState
        ? (b.USED_HEATING_IMPORT ?? 0) +
          (b.USED_COOLING_IMPORT ?? 0) +
          (b.USED_GAS_IMPORT ?? 0) +
          (b.USED_ELECTRICITY_DEMAND ?? 0) +
          (b.USED_ELECTRICITY_GENERATION ?? 0)
        : (b.DISTRICT_HEATING_IMPORT ?? 0) +
          (b.DISTRICT_COOLING_IMPORT ?? 0) +
          (b.GAS_IMPORT_KWH ?? 0) +
          (b.ELECTRICITY_DEMAND ?? 0) +
          (b.ELECTRICITY_GENERATION ?? 0);

      return sumB - sumA;
    });
  };

  const reflowCharts = () => {
    Highcharts.charts.forEach((chart) => chart?.reflow());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      const sorted = co2
        ? [...data].sort((a, b) => b.CO2_USE - a.CO2_USE)
        : sortOnToggle(data);

      setBuildingNamesAndDataForChart(sorted);
    }
  }, [data, co2, toggleState]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      reflowCharts();
    }, 10);
  }, []);

  const options = {
    chart: {
      type: "column",
      polar: false,
    },
    exporting: {
      ...chartExportOption,
      chartOptions: {
        title: {
          text: `${
            co2 ? t("co2EmissionPerBuilding") : t("energyUsePerBuilding")
          }`,
        },
      },
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: "normal",
      },
    },

    title: {
      useHTML: true,
      text: `${co2 ? t("co2EmissionPerBuilding") : t("energyUsePerBuilding")} 
      <span class="custom-tooltip custom-tooltip-left" id="question">?<span class="tooltip-text">${
        co2 ? t("h4") : t("h9")
      }</span>
</span>
      `,
      align: "center",
      style: {
        fontFamily: "Inter, sans-serif",
        fontSize: "15px",
        fontWeight: "600",
        color: "#333333",
      },
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: co2
        ? t("mostRecentCo2UseAvailable")
        : t("mostRecentEnergyUseAvailable"),
    },
    series: co2
      ? [
          {
            data: dataForChart[5],
            name: t("co2Use"),
            color: colorScheme3.renorBlue,
            turboThreshold: 0,
            showInLegend: haveValues(dataForChart[5] ?? []),
          },
        ]
      : [
          {
            data: dataForChart[0],
            name: t("districtHeating"),
            color: colorScheme3.renorRed,
            turboThreshold: 0,
            rounded: false,
            showInLegend: haveValues(dataForChart[0] ?? []),
          },
          {
            data: dataForChart[1],
            name: t("districtCooling"),
            color: colorScheme3.renorBlue,
            turboThreshold: 0,
            showInLegend: haveValues(dataForChart[1] ?? []),
          },
          {
            data: dataForChart[2],
            name: t("gas"),
            color: colorScheme3.renorMediumGray,
            turboThreshold: 0,
            showInLegend: haveValues(dataForChart[2] ?? []),
          },
          {
            data: dataForChart[3],
            name: t("electricity"),
            color: colorScheme3.renorGreen,
            turboThreshold: 0,
            showInLegend: haveValues(dataForChart[3] ?? []),
          },
          {
            data: dataForChart[4],
            name: t("electricityGenerated"),
            color: colorScheme3.renorYellow,
            turboThreshold: 0,
            showInLegend: haveValues(dataForChart[4] ?? []),
          },
        ],
    legend: {
      enabled: true,
      verticalAlign: "top",
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias
        const point: any = this;
        const pointsArray = point?.points;
        const seriesName = point?.x.split(" ");
        const lastPart = seriesName?.pop();
        const firstPart = seriesName?.join(" ");

        const returningData = pointsArray.map((el: any) => {
          const valueToShow = el?.point?.y >= 0 ? el?.point?.y : -el?.point?.y; // Convert negative value back to positive for tooltip display
          if (el?.point?.y !== 0)
            return `<span style="color:${el.point?.color}" >${
              el.point?.series.name
            }</span>: <b>${parseFloat(valueToShow?.toFixed(1))?.toLocaleString(
              "de"
            )}</b> ${co2 ? " kg" : !toggleState ? " MWh" : " kWh/m²"}<br/>`;
        });
        return `<span> ${firstPart}</span><br/>${t(
          "year"
        )}: ${lastPart}<br/> ${returningData.join("")}`;
      },
      shared: true,
    },
    credits: {
      text: "© Renor",
      href: "www.renor.nl",
    },
    pane: {
      background: [],
    },
    responsive: {
      rules: [],
    },
    yAxis: [
      {
        title: {
          text: co2
            ? t("co2Cons") + " [kg/" + t("yearSingular_nocaps") + "]"
            : !toggleState
              ? t("energyUse") + " MWh/" + t("yearSingular_nocaps")
              : t("energyUse") + " kWh/m²." + t("yearSingular_nocaps"),
        },
        labels: {
          formatter: function () {
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias
            const point: any = this;
            return formatYAxisLabel(point.value);
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    xAxis: [
      {
        categories: buildingNames,
        reversed: false,
        visible: data.length < 25,
        type: "category",
        title: { text: " " },
        labels: {
          formatter() {
            if (data.length === 0) return "";
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias
            const point: any = this;
            const valueArray = point?.value?.split(" ");
            const lastValue = valueArray?.pop();
            const firstPart = valueArray?.join(" ");
            return `<span> ${firstPart}</span>`;
          },
        },
      },
    ],

    lang: chartDownloadOptionsTranslations(language || "nl"),
  };```


The most optimal way of updating chart options is by keeping them inside of the useState hook. When updating the state, only the new options are passed to the chart.update method.
const LineChart = () => {
  const initialData = [1, 2, 5, 10];
  const secondaryData = [5, 6, 2, 4];
  const [isToggled, toggleState] = useState(false);
  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({
    title: {
      text: 'Initial data',
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    },
    series: [{ data: initialData }],
  });

  const updateSeries = () => {
    setChartOptions({
      title: {
        text: isToggled ? 'Initial data' : 'Secondary data',
      },
      series: [{ data: isToggled ? initialData : secondaryData }],
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={chartOptions} />
      <button
          onClick={() => {
            toggleState(!isToggled);
            updateSeries();
          }}
        >
          Is toggled: {isToggled ? 'True' : 'False'}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jbcrlq?file=index.js
API: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react?tab=readme-ov-file#optimal-way-to-update
